# When the asynchronous function is invoked, wrap the callback in a closure that will restore context before executing the original re entry code

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, newrelic, apm

I just read the NewRelic documentation about the Context preservation and they have this statement which I don't understand:

> When the asynchronous function is invoked, wrap the callback in a closure that will restore context  before executing the original re entry code.

reference: https://github.com/newrelic/node-newrelic/blob/master/examples/shim/Context-Preservation.md

Is anybody here can expound this statement? Maybe a sample code would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What sample code are you asking about? The statement refers to existing example that is shown above.

Comment: any sample code as long as it is asynchronous.. like filesystem, generic pool, http..